# Compounding scale and rotate transformations skews the content

Tags: css, matrix, rotation, scale, transformation

In CSS3, I'm trying to do this:

```
<div style="position:absolute; 
            left:300px;
            top:300px;
            width:100px; 
            height:50px;
            border:1px solid black; 
            transform: scaleX(2) scaleY(1) rotate(45deg);  ">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

**Live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/m5ESH/1/

As far as I understand it, it should first scale the raster/vectors to 200% horizontally and to 100% vertically and than apply the second transformation to this new raster, that is to rotate each point by 45 degrees.

However notice how the 90 degrees angles (border:solid 1px black) are not in 90 degrees any more. So there is some fundamental flaw in my interpretation of the transformations.

So, **how can I apply a `rotate` transformation that is not affected by previous scale**?

Answer (score 3):

Put the rotate before the scale, then it works as you want it to. [I don't have the theory on why this is the case, it "just works"]

> transform: rotate(45deg) scaleX(2) scaleY(1) ;

Update: multiple transforms are applied by multiplying their underlying transform matrices together. This means that the transforms are applied in *reverse* order. So whatever order you want your transforms applied in, list them in reverse order and they should work.

Comment: Not really. I have some more not-related transformations there (translate) and when it comes to transformations, order matters. This is a different transformation.